# android:nextFocusDown doesn't work

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, imeoptions

I designed a layout with four EditText and i want to facilitate the navigation of them. I understand the use of `android:nextFocusDown` but i'm not able to get it to work. I also setted the ´ImeOptions´ to actionNext, but on the softpad I neither see the right icon.

My XML snippet:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reservation_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reservation"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/yourName"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/reservation_surname" >

            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reservation_surname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reservation"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/yourSurname"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/reservation_email"
                android:nextFocusUp="@+id/reservation_surname" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reservation_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reservation"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/yourEmail"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/reservation_notes"
                android:nextFocusUp="@+id/reservation_email" />

           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reservation_notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reservation"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/reservation_notes" />
```

Comment: replace `android:nextFocusDown` with `android:nextFocusRight`

Comment: Already tryied, nothing changes...

Comment: android:singleLine="true"

Comment: Oh great... `android:singleLine="true"` works, but not when i use as my last edittext `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`. Is it possible to combine them?

Comment: From what I remember both `Return/Enter` and `Next/Done` sit in the same position on the soft keyboard so it it is one or the other from that perspective

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, where nextFocus* simply did not work. In your case..
going from

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/reservation_name"...
          android:nextFocusDown="@+id/reservation_notes"
```

to

change surname's id to NOT have a "+" i.e. 
`<EditText android:id="@id/reservation_surname"` 
this way you are
no creating a new reference to that tag.
This will now work.